# How can I create an onclick event that records two different values in an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onclick

I am trying to create an onclick event where when you press two different buttons with different values they are added to the input field. For example, the input value would appear as: `"13577002, 13577003"` when both buttons are clicked. Can this be done?

```js
< script >
  function myFunction(name) {
    document.getElementById("peep").value = name;
  } < /script>
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><a onclick="myFunction('13577002')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myReserve" href="# style=" font-size:10px " class="btn btn-special-sm btn-color btn-xs ">RESERVE NOW</a></td>
            <td><a onclick="myFunction( '13577003') " data-toggle="modal "  data-target="#myReserve " href="# style="font-size:10px" class="btn btn-special-sm btn-color btn-xs">RESERVE NOW</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <form>
    <label>SKU:
      <input type="text" name="sku" id="peep"></input>
    </label>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent unwanted additions, you could do something like this:

```
 function myFunction(name) {
      field=document.getElementById("peep");
     if(field.value!='' && field.value.split(',').length<2 && field.value!=name) {
         console.log(field.value.split(','));
         field.value+=', '+name;
     }
      else if(field.value=='') {
          field.value=name;
      }


  }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7mjv2sp2/3/ 
Actually one more additional condition is needed, too, so user can't enter more that two values, and they must be different... :)

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I was looking for!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. :) And of course, all this can be easily bypassed - so, server side checking of input(s) is a must.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a boolean flag to determine if something is already stored in there, and then concatenate appropriately

```
if(peepFlag)
    document.getElementById("peep").value += ", " + name;
else {
    document.getElementById("peep").value = name;
    peepFlag = true;
}
```

If you don't anticipate ever needing to do anything else with it, you really don't even need the flag or if statements. But, I'll keep them for the sake of thoroughness

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    function myFunction(name) {
        document.getElementById("peep").value += (',' + name);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is the basic idea but `.value += (',' + name);` would end up with `1357700213577002135770021357700213577002`... if someone clicks it more than once.

Comment: I suppose if you wanted to get really crazy you could just add an array of source elements and check it every time to make sure you can't add the same one twice. That'd be the super thoughtful thing to do, heh.

Answer (score 0):

Hi man check this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/apbuuhch/1/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a data-source="13577002" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myReserve" href="javascript:void(0)" style="font-size:10px" class="btn btn-special-sm btn-color btn-xs">
        RESERVE NOW
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a data-source="13577003" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myReserve" href="javascript:void(0)" style="font-size:10px" class="btn btn-special-sm btn-color btn-xs">
        RESERVE NOW
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<form>
  <label>SKU:
    <input type="text" name="sku" id="peep"></input>
  </label>
</form>
```

js

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
  $("#peep").val($(this).data('source'));
});
```

Comment: As is, this simply replaced the value on each click.